# ViewModel scoping across Fragments in same Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I'm having a problem that I think traces back to `ViewModel` scoping. I have two fragments in the same nav graph under the same activity. The first fragment, `LoginFragment` instantiates a `UserDataViewModel` and populates some of its data in an object called `UserData`

The second fragment, `TodayFragment` is supposed to pick up `UserDataViewModel` and use the attributes already populated to do further work. However, by the time that `TodayFragment` attempts to access the `UserData` object, that object is null. To emphasize, `UserDataViewModel` still has the same memory address, but the problem is that it has lost the reference to its data value.

I've stripped this down so that the data is simply pulling a string from `SharedPreferences` and parsing it using GSON.

**LoginFragment**:

```
private lateinit var userDataViewModel: UserDataViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    MyApplication.appComponent?.inject(this)
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)

    userDataViewModel = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProviders
            .of(this, UserDataViewModelFactory(prefs, dataFetcherService))
            .get(UserDataViewModel::class.java)
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")

    userDataViewModel.getUserData()
}
```

**TodayFragment**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity)

    userDataViewModel = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProviders
            .of(this, UserDataViewModelFactory(prefs, dataFetcherService))
            .get(UserDataViewModel::class.java)
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    userDataViewModel
        .getUserData()
        .observe(this, Observer {
            clubId = it.club_id  // <-- this is where it crashes since 'it' is null
        })
}
```

**UserDataViewModel.kt**

```
class UserDataViewModel(
    prefs: SharedPreferences,
    dataFetcherService: DataFetcherService)
    : ViewModel() {

    private val useCase = UserDataUseCase(prefs, dataFetcherService)

    val userData: MutableLiveData<UserData> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<UserData>().apply { loadUserData() }
    }

    fun getUserData(): LiveData<UserData> {
        return userData
    }

    private fun loadUserData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                try {
                    return@withContext useCase.loadUserData(USER_UNKNOWN)
                } catch (t: Throwable) {
                    return@withContext null
                }
            }
                ?.let {
                    userData.postValue(it)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Where it is weird is in the `getUserData()` method in the view model. When I set a breakpoint on these lines:

`return userData`
`MutableLiveData<UserData>().apply { loadUserData() }`
`return@withContext useCase.loadUserData(USER_UNKNOWN)`

those breakpoints are all hit the LoginFragment. But when it enters TodayFragment, it hits on `return userData` in the view model and then immediately jumps back to the observer inside of TodayFragment with a null pointer exception for the value inside of the view model.

I think that makes sense to the extent that the view model itself is instantiated, but why is the value *inside* the view model null?

For debugging purposes, I am hardcoding a response from the usecase and repository to ensure that there is a value populated in the `ViewModel`.

**Screen Shot from LoginFragment**
[image]

**Screen Shot from TodayFragment (extends AbstractWorkoutFragment)**
*Note how `mData` is now null but the ViewModel is the same.*
[image]

Comment: How do you define implement `UserDataViewModelFactory`?

Answer (score 3):

In each of the fragments you are getting the instance of `ViewModel` this way:

```
ViewModelProviders
        .of(this, UserDataViewModelFactory(prefs, dataFetcherService))
```

Pay attention to `this`, which points to `Fragment.this`. This means, that as a `LifecycleOwner` you are providing the instance of `Fragment`. Hence, each of Fragments will create its own fresh instance of `UserDataViewModel`.

Instead, what you actually want is to reuse the same instance of the `ViewModel`, which means, that as a `LifecycleOwner` you should pass in the hosting activity:

```
ViewModelProviders
        .of(requireActivity(), UserDataViewModelFactory(prefs, dataFetcherService))
```

This way you will get the same instance of the `ViewModel` in both `Fragments`.

Answer (score 3):

In this situation, you can use the navGraphViewModels() property delegate to retrieve a ViewModel from within a fragment destination and by doing that you can get access to viewmodel "attached" to your nav graph

so normally you can use the following in `LoginFragment` and `TodayFragment`

```
private val userDataViewModel: UserDataViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.youNavGraphID)
```

but in your case, you are passing parameters into your view model when you initialize it, so you will have to pass a `ViewModelProvider.Factory` as well

```
private val sharedViewModel: BookViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.navGraph, ::viewModelProducer)

fun viewModelProducer(): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    return object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            return UserDataViewModelFactory(prefs, dataFetcherService) as T
        }
    }
}
```

instead of just

```
 userDataViewModel = activity?.run {
    ViewModelProviders
        .of(this, UserDataViewModelFactory(prefs, dataFetcherService))
        .get(UserDataViewModel::class.java)
} ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
```

--- **UPDATE** ---

I just faced the same situation. I will keep my previous answer but I believe the solution below should solve your problem.

When you are initializing an Activity/Fragments scoped view model you shouldn't pass `this` in the `ViewModelProviders.of()`, because that would mean the `Fragment` itself instead of the activity.

```
 userDataViewModel = activity?.run {
    ViewModelProviders
        .of(this, UserDataViewModelFactory(prefs, dataFetcherService))
        .get(UserDataViewModel::class.java)
} ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
```

Instead, you should use the activity as follows.

```
userDataViewModel = activity?.run {
    ViewModelProviders
        .of(it, UserDataViewModelFactory(prefs, dataFetcherService))
        .get(UserDataViewModel::class.java)
} ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
```

Answer (score 0):

according to 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle

The ViewModel remains in memory until the Lifecycle it's scoped to goes away permanently: in the case of an activity, when it finishes, **while in the case of a fragment, when it's detached.**

It means, the life of view model binds to activity/fragment, not to the application.

The ViewModelProviders reuses the viewmodel for some cases, but when you navigate from the LoginFragment to TodayFragment on the screen, the viewmodel created by providers and binded to LoginFragment is destroyed, then the new one is created and binged to TodayFragment.

I think that's why you get the null reference.

Note: 
I cannot explain why you get the same memory address between the old one and the new one. As my experience, the freed memory can be reused if no other actions overwrite it. Maybe that's why the memory address has no changed.

Answer (score 0):

Pass Activity Context instead of Fragment Context when creating ViewModel. ViewModels will live as long as activity live.

```
val activityContext = getActivity()
ViewModelProviders.of(activityContext, ...)
```

Comment: As activity destroyed you leave a reference to it in the ViewModel.

Comment: @RonTLV so how you explain this, it is recommended by google: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: why down vote for the answer,  passing activity context keeps common view model for all the fragments that lies in. UPVOTE. This is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping I understand your issue, here are some advice

1. Try changing your ViewModel to `class UserDataViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)`. So that the instance is tied to the application lifecycle.
2. Setting clubId could be `it?.apply { setClubId(club_id) }` so that the app acts when actual data is available.
3. Each Fragment should be independent of the other such that you navigate using say `view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_today_fragment)` from inside the LoginFragment. Essentially you rely on the graph entirely for navigation. And use the ViewModel for holding data.

Also the data source should not be passed in from the Activity/Fragment (e.g. your SharedPref use seems incorrect). It should be

```
Activities/Fragments <--- ViewModel <------ DataSources
```